# Spring Boot Race Condition between PropertySource and ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, race-condition

I have a custom starter that other projects depends on, and that starter applies some configurations including a PropertySource

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-geoip.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class CustomStarterAutoConfiguration
{...}
```

application-geoip.yml contains properties specific to it's business and an enablement value

```
...
geoip2:
  enabled: true
...
```

The starter provides the geoip beans with condition to above enabled parameter.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "geoip2")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "geoip2", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class GeoIP2ConfigurationProperties {...}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "geoip2", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class GeoIPConfig {
      // define required beans here with dependency to config from above @Configuration bean
}
```

I ship my starter with this and then create a project depending on this starter.

In my project, when I check above beans (even the property already set to true) in the context I can not see the beans initiated.

Debugged a bit and see that; While annotation `ConditionalOnProperty` is being processed, the context does not have the geoip2.enabled set. But If I wait until the app start and listen the `ApplicationStartedEvent` event. I can see the property is there.

```
event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getProperty("geoip2.enabled") returns true.
```

so If I am assuming it correct, the `PropertySource` annotation seems to processed after `ConditionalOnProperty` annotation. Not always, but mostly. Depends on who wins the race.

Why I am trying this, I would like to carry the property from core with a default value. then using projects can override it in their own application.yaml files. I treid to add the property on simple project's application.yaml file and this time the property picked up and beans initiated as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `@PropertySource`, your custom starter should provide an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation that's registered in `META-INF/spring.factories`. This post-processor is called once the `Environment` has been created but before the application context is refreshed and any beans are created. It should add a `PropertySource` to the environment that contains the `geoip2` properties. If you position your `PropertySource` appropriately, these properties could then be overridden by those in the user's `application.yaml` file.

You can learn more in [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.application.customize-the-environment-or-application-context).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I am hitting the “caution” section in the ref doc. And is the “race condition outcome” true in my experiment ? What do you mean, if I put resource properly to be able to override the value ?

Comment: One last question, would it be the same if I have a dependency to Environtment in my @Bean annotated method. So that, spring will be waiting for environment with all property sources etc populated. I know it's a workaround, but I just wanted to learn :)

Comment: It's not really a race condition as everything is happening serially. It's an ordering problem. For your original attempt to work, things have to happen in a certain order and that order isn't guaranteed. Injecting the environment into a `@Bean` method will have the same problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience and guidance.